# byobu session names starting with underscore

Tags: tmux, byobu

I notice (via `byobu ls` or "Move focus among sessions" `Alt-Up/Down`) that there are some sessions that begin with underscore and I am sure I have not named the sessions like that :) They look as if they are linked to other sessions that do no start with underscore, because if I add or remove windows from the linked session, the ones starting with underscore reflect the change.

I also notice in the `byobu ls` that sessions are part of something called "group".

So I'd like to ask:

1. what are the sessions that begin with underscore and if I can
   avoid cycling through them
2. what is a `group` in byobu (in case it's related)

I have searched the man page and the help page for "group" or "underscore" but I couldn't find something. I also watched all of https://youtu.be/NawuGmcvKus but didn't see anything mentioned.

Example output:

```
ubuntu:~ $ byobu ls
apple: 1 windows (created Wed Jun 12 09:26:46 2019) [190x44] (group carrot)
banana: 2 windows (created Wed Jun 12 10:14:10 2019) [190x44]
_carrot-17655: 1 windows (created Wed Jun 12 09:29:55 2019) [190x43] (group carrot) (attached)
_egg-11803: 7 windows (created Wed Jun 12 09:19:28 2019) [190x44] (group egg)
fig: 7 windows (created Wed Jun 12 09:15:27 2019) [190x44] (group egg)
```

My environment:

```
ubuntu:~ $ byobu --version
byobu version 5.125
tmux 2.6

ubuntu:~ $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/927187/byobu-cache-or-restored-duplicate-sessions

Comment: Related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/byobu/+bug/1785639